# Weird keyboard behavior on pop os?

Tags: linux, keyboard, gnome, pop-os

Hey I have been using pop os for a while now ,But today suddenly my inbuilt keyboard in my laptop is acting weirdly for some keys its doing some other functions

**for ex:
pressing y will take a screenshot
pressing b will turn on scroll lock**

etc

I tried booting into console using `ctrl-alt-f3` and recorded the keycodes for some of the keys that were acting up strange using

```
showkey --scancode
```

the output was
`0x9c` for `enter/return`

`0x15 0x95` for `y` (taking screen shot now)

`0x19 0x99` for `p` (don't know what it does)

`0x2e 0xae` for `c` (don't know what it does)

`0x30 0xb0` for `b` (turning scrolllock on/off)

`0xe0 0x4b`
`0xe0 0xcb` for left arrow key (don't know what it does)

`0xe0 0x4d`
`0xe0 0xcd` for `right arrow key` (don't know what it does)

`0x39 0xb9` for `spacebar` (don't know what it does)

`0x01`
`0x01` for `escape` (don't know what it does)

fortunately the external keyboard works fine can anyone please help me out on this
I have tried the solutions given to ubuntu but non of them worked

Comment: I believe those scancodes are correct.  Therefore the problem probably lies in either the keyboard mapping, or more likely, the modifiers.  Try pressing and releasing, one at a time, each shift, control, alt, meta, etc... key (from the keyboard with issues).

Comment: ...and if all else fails, restarting your X server will probably fix it.

Comment: No sir the keys won't even work in the bios it self I thought the problem is with pop os and installed windows to see if I can tweek the drivers a little bit but no changes at all even after uninstalling and reinstalling drivers it still works the same and I manged to get the list of keys which are acting weirdly.

Comment: y -> screenshot
p -> pause
n-> scroll lock
b-> ctrl+cancel
up arrow -> page up
down arrow -> next
right Arrow -> end
left arrow -> home
space bar -> does nothing,  I got these from an software called carnac

Comment: If the problem exists in other OSes, then the problem may lie in the hardware.  Maybe it is configured as some other style of keyboard.  Maybe this is a laptop keyboard and the Function key is stuck down.  Try power-cycling it.  Try checking for BIOS keyboard settings.

Comment: Thank you so much sir a couple of hard taps on the FN key seems to have resolved the Issue as you said the fn key might have stuck down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe those scancodes are correct.
Therefore the problem probably lies in either the keyboard mapping, or more likely, the modifiers.
Try pressing and releasing, one at a time, each shift, control, alt, meta, etc... key (from the keyboard with issues).

OP then reported that it happened in other operating systems, so:

If the problem exists in other OSes, then the problem may lie in the hardware.
Maybe it is configured as some other style of keyboard.
Maybe this is a laptop keyboard and the Function key is stuck down.
Try power-cycling it.
Try checking for BIOS keyboard settings.